# Move files in nested directories to dest folder but keep basename and discard folder structure?

Tags: rename, mv

```
find $(MY_DIR)/source -type f -name "*.wav3" -print0 | \
xargs -0 -P $(NPROC) -n1 -I {} \
mv {} $(MY_DIR)/sound/{}.wav
```

From the above I'm trying to find all .wav3 files, move them to the sound folder however I'm not too sure how to trim the output file to just retain its basename:

`$(MY_DIR)/source/deeply/nested/file/song1.wav3`

`$(MY_DIR)/source/deeply/nested/file/song2.mp3.wav3`

will be moved to:

`$(MY_DIR)/sound/song1.wav`

`$(MY_DIR)/sound/song2.wav`

How can I adjust my script?

Comment: it would strip `.song.wav3` and keep `old` as basename.

Comment: use parameter expansion via `sh -c ...` e.g. `find $(MY_DIR)/source -type f -name "*.wav3"  -exec sh -c 'bn=${0##*/}; dn="${bn%%.*}".wav; printf %s\\n "$dn"' {} \;` will find your files and print the destination files names... It's easy to change that to move each file to the new `dn` . Post an answer if you manage to do the rest

Comment: @don_crissti That should be `sh -c '...' sh`, the arguments start with `$0`.  FWIW.

Comment: @SatoKatsura - works fine like that if you don't care much about error stuff... if you do `sh -c '...' sh` you have to use `$1` instead of `$0`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing with `find` + `xargs` + `mv` just switch to `zsh` and do

```
autoload -U zmv
zmv -n '$(MY_DIR)/source/**/(*).wav3' '$(MY_DIR)/source/${1%%.*}.wav'
```

How it works:

- first we load `zmv` via `autoload`
- `-n` parameter is to prevent execution, just see what it will do, and if you are happy with the output remove this option
- double star `**` match all nested directories
- `(*)` match anything and store the result in `$1` variable
- `${1%%.*}` strip the first dot all subsequent characters
- and finally add `.wav` extension

Comment: I'm actually using this in a makefile and is expected to be used on a linux flavored server, is there any way to not introduce any dependencies?